# Боковое меню в Android

Tags: android, menu

начал изучать android разработку недавно. Писал небольшое приложение на android и в нем нужно сделать **боковое меню** . Я пробовал сделать с шаблоном из Android Studio, *Navigation Drawer Activity*, но раз я обращаюсь к вам, понятно, что у меня ничего не получилось. Я много гуглил свой вопрос, но нигде не нахожу подходящего туториала(единственное исключение, наверное является [эта шикарная статья с Хабра](https://habr.com/ru/post/449776/), но вот зараза, здесь написано на Kotlin, а мне нужно на Java), пожалуйста  расскажите ***ПОШАГОВО***, **как создать боковое меню в Android Studio?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вот инструкция как добавить в приложение нужный вам макет. Будем рассматривать ситуацию, когда вы будете создавать новое приложение, учитывая приведенную информацию в вопросе. При создании нового проекта вы можете выбрать Drawer activity как вы уже пробовали и дальше студия все сделает за вас. Будут созданы все необходимые классы для поддержки, разметка (которую можно будет кастомизировать по вашему усмотрению), ресурсы для меню и тому подобное. Разобраться что для чего в таком варианте совсем несложно. Есть второй вариант - создавать приложение на основе пустой активности (Empty activity) и дальше все делать вручную. Для начала нужно создать проект и перейти в файл разметки `activity_main.xml` и добавить соответствующий код:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <!-- The main content view -->
     <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/content_frame"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
      <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
             android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
             android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Дальше вам нужно добавить пункты меню которые будут отображаться, для этого переходим в файл строковых ресурсов и добавляем массив со своими данными:

```
<string-array name="screen_array">
        <item>Screen 1</item>
        <item>Screen 2</item>
        <item>Screen 3</item>
   </string-array>
```

Следующим шагом будет создание разметки пункта меню, поэтому создаем файл `drawer_list_item.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/activated_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

После создания разметки пункта меню, нужно подумать над тем как будет отображаться нажатия и отмечание выбранного пункта меню, поэтому создаем в папке `drawable` файл `activated_background.xml` :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

и в ресурсах цвета добавляем нужный цвет:

```
<item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
```

После того как с оформлением закончено нужно подумать над логикой поведения нашего меню, вот активность:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] mScreenTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mScreenTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.screen_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mScreenTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
                ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Initialize the first fragment when the application first loads.
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
         // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            // Show toast about click.
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.action_search, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

     /* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ScreenOne();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ScreenTwo();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ScreenThree();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mScreenTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // Error
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Error. Fragment is not created");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

ну и для корректной работы вам нужно создать необходимое кол-во фрагментов, которые будут показывать пользователю какие-то данные:

```
public class ScreenOne extends Fragment {

    public ScreenOne() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_first, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

на каждом фрагменте можно сделать свою разметку. Вот [туториал](https://habr.com/ru/post/236567/).

Comment: можете написать подробнее что в какой файл писать?

Answer (score 1):

Не будет вам тут пошагового решения. Читайте [правила сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help), оно не любит таких подходов. Тут помогают решить конкретную проблему, а не пишут мануалы под заказ.

> но раз я обращаюсь к вам, понятно, что у меня ничего не получилось

Раз не получилось - значит что-то вы сделали не так. Все шаблоны студии работают из коробки, проверено уже даже не одним поколением программеров. Если он не заработал у вас - создайте новый вопрос, где укажите что именно не так: какую ошибку выдает при запуске, например. А вот такие вопросы будут довольно шустро минусоваться и удаляться.

Comment: уже когда дописывал ответ вы написали)) стирать было жалко, но вообще вы правы такие вопросы чаще всего закрывают. Студия в таких процессах помогает лучше чем туториал :)

Comment: А я вот поленился, так что респект за усидчивость =)

Comment: все с чего-то начинают, нужно относится с пониманием к таким мелким проблемам)) но вы тоже по своему правы))